# Recording Heartbeats

Tags: recording, microphone, human, contact-mic

What microphone would be appropriate to record heartbeats? I want to record people off the street so it has to be easy for the person to hold in place themselves for a couple of minutes whilst standing up without causing too many extraneous noises. It would be great if it gave the impression of 'medically legitimate professional' rather than 'home-made pervert freak'.

It's being made in London to form part of the music for a modern dance show in Korea.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are recording in a very controlled environment, I would recommend a contact mic (which is, ultimately, a better-sounding stethoscope). A standard capsule-based mic will likely generate too much noise (or pick up noise from the surrounding area) because you'll need to turn it up significantly to pick up a pulse.

Check these out: http://www.c-ducer.com/

They are contact mics that could easily be mistaken for medical electrodes but anyone who doesn't know better (it basically feels like a leather strip, and it comes with its own double-sided tape). I own a pair and they sound fantastic — very low noise and they come in a kit with a phantom-powered impedance convertor that terminates in a standard XLR to plug in to any preamp. They're advertised for violin, harp, piano, and any instrument where there is a resonant body. Properly fitted to the upper chest and/or neck, I'm sure you could get some good heartbeat sounds.

Best,
~Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt. A friend has offered to lend me a pair of harp mics which sound very similar.

Comment: How did this option turn out? Very curious!

Answer (score 2):

You could try Diego Stocco's method. Check out his [stethoscope mic at :24](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fY-ZoVMwGKM). Looks like a Rode NT-6 with a modded stethoscope attachment.

Comment: That's a brilliant trick. Maybe it's a lot harder to do than it looks but I will try it. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

come on, there's got to be a more extreme version that involves ingesting things or, you know, probing of some sort. :D

Comment: To be honest, I think people off the street will be a little uncomfortable about that...
"I have to stick it WHERE?"

Comment: What about spill, bleed and leakage?

Comment: @David - Hahaha :-D

Answer (score 1):

I have done some great hartbeat recordings with the H2a Hydrophone from Aquarian.
It may be a good idea to try with the [adapter](http://www.aquarianaudio.com/contact-mic-adapter.html)

Comment: Ditto, better results with the adapter than without.

Answer (score 0):

Hello !

If you've got one, you could try with a hydrophone mic in contact with your chest.
It's not the best way, because you will have noise to deal with, but maybe you can get what you're looking for.

Clem

Answer (score 0):

@Clem. If you're using a hydrophone, you could do the recording underwater in contact with your chest. This might actually make it feel like you're inside the bloodstream. You would need a very quiet body of water, though.

Comment: with regards to quiet bodies of water - that probably rules out urban swimming pools.  Those things pick up traffic noise like crazy!

Comment: That's a great idea. Will try it in the bath.